# How to set new index and remove default index in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have attached the dataframe in the pic.
In the df, subVoyageID is the default index, I am trying to remove that blank row next to the subvoyageID, so that all the column names are aligned in the same row, but I am unable to do it.

Since subVoyageID is the default index, I copied the data into new col "svid" and reset the index to new column "svid", (see the code and pic below)

```
    df["SVID"] = df.index
    df.set_index('SVID')
    df
```

Original df

[image: orig df]

Resultant df

[image: new df]

Now how do I get rid of the very first column which was the default index, as df.info() shows 5 columns from x-max to SVID; Or is there any other way I could align all the column labels in one row. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert index values to column and if necessary `rename` column:

```
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'subVoyageID':'SVID'})
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `subVoyageID` isn't a *column*, it is your *index*. Just use [`reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to make it an actual column.

**Example**

```
>>> df

         a  b  c
myindex         
0        0  1  2
1        3  4  5
2        6  7  8

>>> df.reset_index().rename(columns={df.index.name: 'not my index'})

   not my index  a  b  c
0             0  0  1  2
1             1  3  4  5
2             2  6  7  8
```